# Composite C1 - User Control not showing on page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, c1-cms

I have a website created with Composite C1, and I'm attempting to display a user control on a page using the Composite.AspNet.LoadUserControl function. Just following the example on the website with a very simple user control that simply outputs hello world in a heading 1 element doesn't seem to show anything. You can see the page here:

http://wallbro.plazacommerce.com/Contact

Where the user control is supposed to be rendered within the HTML, all I see is:

```
<c1marker:marker xmlns:c1marker="http://www.composite.net/ns/asp.net/controls" key="[Composite.Function.Render.Asp.Net.Control.0]" />
```

The user control consists of:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.ascx.cs" Inherits="Frontend_Controls_Test" %>
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Is there anything else that I need to do? I can't find any other help on this issue, and it seems so simple that it must be something obvious that I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Paul, sorry if i intrepreted wrongly.
I have searched for c1marker for but i didnt find anything.

Do u mean insertng user control created in front end as i noticed **"Frontend_Controls_Test"**

```
 <f:function xmlns:f="http://www.composite.net/ns/function/1.0"        
 name="Composite.AspNet.LoadUserControl">
  <f:param name="Path" value="~/frontend/Test.ascx" />  </f:function>
```

**name="Path" value="~/frontend/Test.ascx"**

Here relative path with respect to frontend can be given.
if my interpretation is totally wrong please forgive.Also please tell me where is this c1marker:marker

Is it there in composite solution...or is it some customization made

Vishnu Nadesh

Comment: Hi Vishnu, If you go to the page and view the source code and do a search for c1marker:marker you'll see this in the HTML instead of the HTML that is inside the user control.